# Query a image database with mouse coords

Tags: php, database, image, drupal, coordinates

Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

I am looking for some options/suggestions/general comments on how I might be able to query a database of images based on mouse location.

Essentially, I have a database (on a seperate companies server) that contains a few images, what I would like to do is return an image to my website depending on where my mouse is based in the browser.

so if I click top left, i'll get a zoomed in picture of the top left of the landscape (a seperate image), if I click bottom right, I will get a zoomed in picture of the bottom right (again, seperate image).

I am a newbie to HTML/PHP/CSS but not to C++/C/Delphi, I'm sure I can do this, but I can't see the wood from the trees as to what I actually have to do!

I am using my own server (hosted by 1&1) and a Drupal webpage.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Many thanks for your time,

Kay

Comment: server-side image maps will send the x/y coords of clicks on the image to the server, which you'd then process however... http://www.jimthatcher.com/webcourse5.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) and use javascript (probably jQuery) to bind to each `<area>` and do something (in your case, popup/zoom a separate image)

Comment: Thanks guys, thats exactly what I was looking for. so I need to be getting involved with Image Maps. just one thing that has crossed my mind, as an improvement (this is how brand new the idea is!) is it possible to do it with a "click and hold" type event? a OnMouseDown event if you will? then I could click the image and drag my mouse accross and all the sub images would pop up as required?